# Object-based alignment guides in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, alignment

In **InDesign**, I never have a problem aligning objects in relation to other objects because the **Guides** always show me where each object's center points are:

[image]

I would love to know how to do this in **Illustrator CC 2018**. In my menus, **Smart Guides** are enabled and yet I cannot see objects' centers when trying to align by dragging another object near or inside it:

[image]

Comment: Its pssible to get it to work like this but due to a illustrator scene easily having thousands of objects it really becomes tedious after a while. Check in preferences what parts of smart guides you have active and which you have turned off. Having them all on at the same time causes a Huge mess.

Comment: Could you expand on that? The option is not to be found in the "Guides & Grids" or "Smart Guides" Preference Tabs of Illustrator. How would one end up with "thousands" of objects in a scene if they're not able to align correctly two of them to begin with 

Comment: Well i find that being able to align to object center works even without alignment guides. And i am perfectly capable of doing very precise work without it. But then im snapping to vertices and intersections mostly anyway.

Comment: lets take a example [**this image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpAuY.png) is a quite simple (technical) doodle that i drew back in 2011 because of boredom (shared because ive shared it before). Its a pretty simple drawing it only has 70 objects in it, that means also 70 centers. Doing any alignment would become very tedious. OH and PS: you need to disable some snapping options under the or illustrator tends to become quite wild.

Comment: Maybe you should explain your workflow in further detail somewhere, because I have no idea how you work. I'm talking about a situation where you have, say, illustrations and text blocks. Obviously you'd Lock a lot of stuff into place as you move along in order not to move things by mistake. A drawing like the one you are sharing belongs to different kind of workflow, if I had to produce such an image I would probably use Blender with SVG export.

Comment: 2/ Imagine doing a mockup [like such](https://i.graphicmama.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/14083941/dream-car-collection.jpg), you'll align the slider buttons at the bottom, then Lock them once and for all. One could decide to do that through the Align panel, or just align freehandedly using smart guides (what I'm asking about). Then you place the text and "Start" button on each side, then the (hopefully grouped) illustration in the middle, all these steps need guides for precision.

Comment: I dont know about you but atleast my illustrator cc aligns to the center just like your indesign if i choose to enable the alignment guides and the object has a center enabled in its attributes (and you disable the guide features you dont need). But i dont have CC at home intentionally. And yes if wanted to do a engineering drawing i 3d i would use a CAD application, then at least my curves wouldn't be a bunch of linear segments once i export and i would be done in less time than it takes for you to start blenders rendering engine. But it is a doodle not a efficiency most my work is more cplx

Comment: I can't replicate this issue in Illustrator CC 2017.  [See screen capture here](https://imgur.com/a/82RnR). Perhaps it's a bug in 2018.  I have no intention upgrading just yet to find out.

Comment: It works fine in CC2018 as well. It merely works *differently* than InDesign. If you want InDesign and Illustrator Smart Guides to work the same.... you need to harp on Adobe. Good luck with that.

Comment: Ok @Scott could you explain further please? What options do you have checked?

Comment: Joojaa has already explained.. turn on the center point (Attributes panel) and then the Alignment guides in Smart Guides preferences. It works fine. It will *not* work the same way InDesign works. You need to complain to Adobe if you want the two apps to operate the same. Illustrator smart guides are far more picky than Indesign smart guides due to the nature of the more free-form editing in Illustrator.

Comment: @MicroMachine are you working on a Mac?

Comment: @Confused yes I am working on a Mac

Comment: @joojaa if the answer is a particular setting could you please leave that as the appropriate answer so we can mark it accepted.

Comment: @MicroMachine I thought so. Illustrator on Mac runs like a stuck pig. It has all sorts of UI performance problems you've probably already noticed. Snapping is adversely impacted by this. As are modifying a blends extents, group editing and a bunch of other layer operations. If you have any chance of running bootcamp, Illustrator under windows, on the same hardware, will run noticeably faster and smoother, with far fewer issues. Parallels, VMWare and other virtualised Windows on a Mac do not provide these same benefits/boosts in performance. Only bootcamp.

Comment: @Confused too much hassle to run 2 OSes on a virtual disk. If I can do it quick and easy in Id, why bother doing it in Ai? Like so many things... Drop a Photo on a shape in Id and you got a clipping mask in seconds (but easier to move/resize the photo inside the shape in Id...) - copy/paste the result in Ai, same result, much faster. Make a square with opposite sides rounded: 1 minute in Id, 10 minutes in Ai... That and other reasons make using Ai rare for me. Id is a powerhorse for layout.